# Connecting myPHPAdmin (Azure) to MySqlb (Azure) through SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service, azure-mysql-database

I got MySQL 8 on Azure with 'Enfore SSL Connection' **Enabled**

Configured connection string to above in MySQL in App with connection string (Web App) provided by above MySQL

Which is

```
Database={your_database}; Data Source=xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com; User Id=xxx@xxxx; Password={your_password}
```

When trying to manage the MySQL in phpmyAdmin getting below error

```
#9002 - SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

There is no option to specify SSL Mode on the Web App Connection String.

***[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/mysql/concepts-ssl-connection-security):***

Default settings
By default, the database service should be configured to require SSL connections when connecting to MySQL. We recommend to avoid disabling the SSL option whenever possible.

When provisioning a new Azure Database for MySQL server through the Azure portal and CLI, enforcement of SSL connections is enabled by default.

Connection strings for various programming languages are shown in the Azure portal. Those connection strings include the required SSL parameters to connect to your database. In the Azure portal, select your server. ***Under the Settings heading, select the Connection strings. The SSL parameter varies based on the connector, for example "ssl=true" or "sslmode=require" or "sslmode=required" and other variations.***

Comment: @Streedhar, did you install the myPHPAdmin from the gallery or via the MySQL In-App blade (the Manage link)

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT: Installed as extension from Kudu and updated the config file. It doesn't work.  Raised support request with Microsoft.   Ended up create whole PHP Web App with myPHPAdmin code and updated the config file.  No good now.

Comment: @Sreedhar did you get any clue how to resolve this ?